# height definition in flex box with responsive images - Chrome/Safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, flexbox

The following simple [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gxBQYR) results in different behaviours in Chrome and Safari.

here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 d-flex">
        <img class="main-img" src="http://placehold.it/2000x1000.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 d-flex">
        <p>Lorem<br><br><br><br><br>Ipsum</br></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the CSS

```
.d-flex{
  background-color: #999999;
}

div > img {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

div > p {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Specifically in Safari there is no extra space neither above nor below the img, whereas in Chrome there is a huge space

It seems as if Chrome first checks the img height to reserve the space and then shrinks the img for width:100%
whereas Safari first sets width:100% and then set the height of the enclosing div.

How to make Chrome behave like Safari?

Comment: Please review and comment on my answer, and let me know if something is unclear or missing. If not, then it would be great if you could accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Because of inconsistency between browsers, `img` as flex items might render differently.

In this case, add a wrapper around the `img`.

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EvdJPW)

Stack snippet

```css
.d-flex{
  background-color: #999999;
}

div > img {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

div > p {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 d-flex">
    <div>
      <img class="main-img" src="http://placehold.it/2000x1000.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 d-flex">
    <p>Lorem<br><br><br><br><br>Ipsum<br></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Another option is to remove `d-flex` from the first `col-md-6`

[Updated codepen 2](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dzgLOm)